# Setting up a (Linux) Hadoop cluster

Tags: linux, hadoop, cluster-computing

Do you need to set up a Linux cluster first in order to setup a Hadoop cluster ?

Answer (score 2):

No. Hadoop has its own software to manage a "cluster". Just install linux and make sure the machines can talk to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying the Hadoop software, along with the appropriate config files, and starting it on each node (which Hadoop can do automatically) creates the cluster from the Linux machines you have.  So, no, by that definition you don't need to have a separate linux cluster.  If your question is whether or not you need to have a multiple-machine cluster to use Hadoop: no, you can run Hadoop on a single machine for either testing or small-sized jobs, via either local mode (where everything is confined to a single process) or pseudodistributed mode (where you trick Hadoop into thinking it's running on multiple computers).